# If $A$ and $B$ are infinite sets and $|A|=|B|$, then prove $|A|=|A∪B|$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

So far I've only figured out that $A\cup B$ is also infinite. Where to go from there? Thanks.

Comment: Can you tell us what do you mean by ~ ?

Comment: equivalence, so there is bijection between two sets :)

Comment: You could do transfinite induction on cardinals. Are you familiar with cardinals? I am not sure if you want an answer with that technique

Answer (score 0):

if $A$ infinite then $A \sim A\dot{\cup}A:=A\times\left\{1,2\right\}$ and thus $A \sim A \dot{\cup} B$ which implies $A \sim A\cup B$ because $A\subset A\cup B\subset A\dot{\cup} B$.

Comment: uhm.... i think you could use $\tilde{A}_{1}:=\left\{\left(a,1\right)|a\in A\right\}$, $\tilde{A}_{2}:=\left\{\left(a,2\right)|a\in A\right\}$, $\tilde{B}_{1}:=\left\{\left(b,1\right)|b\in A\right\}$, $A\sim \tilde{A}_{1}\cup \tilde{A}_{2}\sim \tilde{B}_{1}\cup \tilde{A}_{2}$ and thus $A\sim A\cup B$

Comment: this was actually a comment on a comment asking for a version without $\times$ but the comment vanished